# Typescript properties splitting depending on properties provided

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a hook in React which will accept Component and props for that component and returns a function, which also accepts props of that component but if any non-optional props were already provided in props object when calling hook, then those particular props should become optional in returned function props argument. Consider code below:

**MyComponent accepts props:** name, limit, message are required, other are optional.

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  name: string;
  limit: number;
  message: string;
  delay?: number;
  color?: string;
};

const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
  return <div>{/** */}</div>;
};
```

**useFactory hook accepts component and partial props of that component**

```
type UseFactoryProps<P, T extends Partial<P>> = {
  Component: ComponentType<P>;
  props?: T;
};

type CreateFN<P> = (props: P) => JSX.Element;

const useFactory = <P, T extends Partial<P>>({
  Component,
  props
}: UseFactoryProps<P, T>): CreateFN<P> => {
  const create = (additionalProps: P) => {
    return <Component {...props} {...additionalProps} />;
  };

  return create;
};
```

I want create function to accept additionalProps of same type as component props except props that were non-optional and provided in hook props should be optional now.

**Here in useFactory hook**: I pass required Component prop together with props (this is optional, but I still pass some of required props here, such as name and limit).

```
const App = () => {
  const create = useFactory({
    Component: MyComponent,
    props: { name: 'Some name', limit: 5 }
  });

  create({}); // Create should require to pass message prop

  return null;
};
```

As per above create call, object with message prop should be passed as it is the only non-optional prop that was not passed when calling useFactory hook. Other props here should be optional (name, limit should also be optional as it was already passed in hook).

So in the end I want to have some predefined props and merge them with additional props in create function when creating passed component and passing props and additional props to to that component making sure that all required props will be provided (whether in useFactory props property or when calling create function). Is this even possible?

Comment: You might want to change the name of `ReturnType` because that's already built-in to TypeScript and could confuse others.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5yZm) example help?